# What is a memory efficient way to convert a Scala Map where the keys are indices to Array efficiently?

Tags: arrays, scala, dictionary

I have a Scala Map, where the keys represent indexes and the values represent the value of that index. Essentially, this is a sparse vector.

I am looking to convert this to an Java Array (for use with Spark).

I am using:

```
def toArray[T](input: Map[Int, T]): Array[T] = (0 until scores.keys.max).map(i => input.get(i).orNull).toArray
```

The purpose of this is use in a Spark application. The `T` I am using is a Spark Vector which can be huge (as in, tens of thousands of doubles, MB of data). I'm concerned that what I am doing is to glib and not parsimonious enough in memory usage.

Is there a more memory efficient way to do this?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly: You have a sparse vector returned by spark and you are trying to convert it into a java array for some reason?

Answer (score 2):

I would not classify your solution as "glib".  There is **some** memory over-usage due to allocating a `Range` of `Int` values.  The length of the Range will be `scores.keys.max`, but presumably this memory usage is swamped by the memory allocation for your `T` values.

If you want to avoid this initial allocation you can use an `Iterator`:

```
Iterator
  .range(0, scores.keys.max)
  .map(i => input.get(i).orNull)
  .toArray
```

This will avoid creating an in memory sequence of Int values and instead operate on each index in a lazy manner.